# Magento Foreign Key Constraints

Tags: sql, magento, foreign-keys, constraints

Nobody can order Magento website. I have this message :

```
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bdd_www14`.`salesrule_product_attribute`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALESRULE_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_CUSTOMER_GROUP` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_group_id`) REFERENCES `customer_group` (`customer_group_id`) O)' in [...]/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: could you provide me URL so i can look into it.

Comment: You're trying to insert or update a row which breaks a constraint defined on the database. If this is a real production issue, rollback to the last deployed version of your site. Without more information, I don't think we can help much.

Comment: The URL of te WebSite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Good...

If someone have this, the problem is due to a delete of a group of user. I have restore the group in the database and all is ok.